# ListBox Form Control Scrolling

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've been doing a ton of research and I'm finally giving in and hoping the community can help.  I have a FORM CONTROL list box, not an active x.  I'm intentionally using form control for a variety of reasons that are not necessarily important (unless you can guide me how to 100% ensure activeX controls don't resize themselves on workbook open).  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get the form control list box to scroll to the selected value and put it in view.  Here is what I have:

```
ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 13").Selected = 100
```

The list has 1000 values in it to be selected.  When this runs, #100 is selected, but is not in view.  The list box does not move.

> **How can I get the scrolling to occur so the selected value is at the top?**

ActiveX would be:

```
.TopIndex
```

But that is not available for form controls.

Comment: I couldn't discover any method that controls the visibility of the `Listbox` interior (that will work in Excel). But, addressing your comment about ActiveX controls, you can 100% guarantee that your controls will present with the same size every time the worksheet is opened by resetting the size of those controls programmatically using the `Workbook_Open` event. You can store a list of the controls by name in a hidden worksheet, along with the Top, Left, Width, and Height of each control for "resizing" on Open.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT.  I agree this can be done that way I just hate the workaround.  Will give that another try!  Appreciate if anyone else has any thoughts!

Comment: or use a "Drop Down"?

Comment: Hi Siddharth - I realize there are alternatives but the functionality of a list box is what is critical to my project.

Comment: Set the linked cell address of the combo. Then put the value you want displayed (eg 100) in that linked cell. (I usually hide the linked cell under the combo)

Comment: Well - I'll be.  I've been working with List Boxes for years and always used the Linked Cell as Output of the list box, but never knew you can input a value into the linked cell to drive the selection.  Thanks Harasssed Dad!

Comment: Posted an answer to your question hoping to simplify daily work  - @Mr.Data

Comment: Actually, even the linked cell option does not do it.  Still searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Scroll to given listbox index to be displayed on top of visible list**

> *I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get the form control list box to scroll to the selected value and put it in view.*

Seems that actually there's no standard method (leaving aside API calls) to control the visibility of the listbox interior display for a **form** control list box as opposed to a *Userform*'s **ActiveX** control list box.

**Additional hints**

For the sake of completeness (and due to comment) I demonstrate how to scroll into view in a Userform's listbox by combining both navigation properties - i.e. by setting **`.ListIndex`** as well as **`.TopIndex`** together with a defined index **value** :-), e.g. via a procedure as follows:

**Example calls**

```
  ScrollTo 100          ' attention: zerobased
```

*or*

```
  ScrollTo ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 13").Selected
```

**Helper procedure**

... sets the current `ListIndex` to e.g. 100 *AND* defines it as `.TopIndex`.

(*Side note: of course targets at the very **list end** could be displayed even below `.TopIndex` depending on the actual `.ListCount`*)

```
Private Sub ScrollTo(ByVal idx&)
' Purpose: Scroll to given target index to be displayed on top of visible list
' Site:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813550/listbox-form-control-scrolling 
' Author:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
    Me.ListBox1.TopIndex = idx
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = idx
End Sub
```

Comment: TM - the form control list box does not have a .TopIndex, that is the entire issue.  Only ActiveX list box does.

Comment: Admitted :-), have been referring to a User*form*'s ActiveX `Listbox` and not to the **form** control list box within a sheet; nevertheless this answer might be helpful anyway to complete the listbox theme - @Mr.Data