# ListBox move scroll by selected item

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have create ListBox by Form Controls.

How to move the scrollbar by item selected?

Comment: Sorry, not really understanding what you mean by "How to move the scrollbar by item selected?".  You want to move the scrollbar in the listbox so a particular item is displayed?

Comment: Looks like we are confusing 2 things. You say form controls, so I assume controls that are on a form, but what you actually mean is using a form control on a worksheet. I am not familiar with using listboxes in that way, but I did find another question about this that you may or may not find helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813550/listbox-form-control-scrolling

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much!